# Drools 6 classloader doesn't find compiled java class during runtime

Tags: drools

I have a problem with Drools 6 that makes me debug for a long time now.
Following situation:

We are genereting a drl file and a java class with .java. Both files are compiled via drools  (KieBuilder) and put into the target memory filesystem. I can see no compilation errors and the .class files appears to be there within the given package subdirectory.
The drools Knowledge accesses this class during runtime.
During runtime the .class file does not seem to be in the ClassPath. Do I have to tell drools manually to add .class files that are generated during compile time?

I have tried it with "import packg.MyClasss" statements in the .drl file, using the full qualified name with package.ClassName, using the default package, etc... I am stuck.

Any ideas? Is there some default package that I might have to add before my package?

Thanks

Comment: I'm have seen very similar problems and am also looking for an answer.

With the change from composite class loader to hierarchical, it's not clear to me how to include the Grails application's root class loader to get classes found correctly.

Instead I keep getting NoClassDefFoundError's thrown, which generally means using the wrong class loader.

Someone must have a clue. Someone?

Comment: Hi. In my case the problem was the different classloaders during the production runtime and development runtime with osgi. We had to implement a classloader wrapper class that combines mutltiple classloaders into a wrapper classloader so that the class could be found